# How to deal with 'cached' instance in @ViewScoped page?

Tags: java, jpa, caching, eclipselink

*App running with `JSF`, `Primefaces`, `eclipselink`, not a small app, about 100 pages/bean all working perfectly*

I got some troubles understanding how my `@ViewScoped` page works, I got a `select` UI component, filled with a simple `List<People>` and a back-end `selectedPeople` in my bean

---

```
// all getters, setters, JPA annotations, all good
public class People {
    private String name;
    private List<Car> cars;
}
```

---

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class PeopleBean {
    @EJB
    private Service sPeople;
    private People selectedPeople;
    private List<People> listPpl;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        listPpl = sPeople.readAll();      // always good, same as DB values
    }

    public People getSelectedPeople(){
       return selectedPeople;
    }

    public People setSelectedPeople(People p){     // p is an old element
       selectedPeople = p;                         // BREAKPOINT
    }

    // getter for the list too
    public void method(){
        Logger.getAnoymousLogger().severe(selectedPeople.getCars()); // the one the old people, not the ne contained in the actual list
    }
}
```

---

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="selectP" value="#{peopleBean.selectedPeople}" converted="#{genericSecuerdConverter}" >
    <p:ajax event="change" partialSubmit="true" listener="#{peopleBean.method()}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{peopleBean.listPpl}" var="people" itemLabel="#{people.name}" itemValue="#{people}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Sequence of use and problem is (information taken from debugging) :

- go to `peoplePage.xhtml` where the select element is, `IDs` of the list's element are `#410, #411, #412` (3 peoples)
- go to `modif.xhtml`, change the 3rd people (remove a `car`, saved in DB (check in DB))
- come back to `peoplePage.xhtml`, list is OK, `IDs` in debug are `#650, #651, #652`
- change the value (from `null`) of the *selectUI* to choose a people, and at the breakpoint, `p` appears to be the `#412` element, so the changes on its car's list are not visible, it does not come from the `listPpl` (because contains only valid elements and corresponds to DB),  it's kind of caching

---

I tried to disable *ecpliselink* cache as states [EclipleLink cache](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/FAQ/How_to_disable_the_shared_cache%3F)

- change *eclipselink* property
- change *JPA* propery
- use `@Cacheable(false)`

No one had an effect, nor go to private navigation neither clear the browser cache and come back to the page, the `p` element is still the old one from first loading

I thought `@ViewScoped` allows to open a page each time as if it was the first time, but seems not, can't figure where the element can be stored/cached

---

**Edit** I used a workaround for the moment but this is obviously o the best solution

```
public People setSelectedPeople(People p){    
    if(p!=null)
        selectedPeople = sPeople.read(p.getId());                         
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `@RequestScoped`. It will create everything each and every time you do a suitable HTTP request. Otherwise it is not guaranteed to destroy the `@ViewScoped` beans. An example in the Omnifaces documentation: [ViewScoped](http://omnifaces.org/docs/javadoc/3.2/org/omnifaces/cdi/ViewScoped.html#saveInViewState--).

This feature could be used to help the recreation of the page when the user is using the back and forward buttons of the browser for example.

> ***@RequestScoped***
>   Bean lives as long as the HTTP request-response lives. It gets created upon a HTTP request and gets destroyed when the HTTP response associated with the HTTP request is finished.
>
> ***@ViewScoped***
>   Bean lives as long as the user is interacting with the same JSF view in the browser window/tab. It gets created upon a HTTP request and gets destroyed once the user postbacks to a different view.

Source of descriptions: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_managed_beans.htm